# R change data frame into time series with not standard timestamp

Tags: r

Hi I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   57 obs. of  4 variables:
$ timestamp: Factor w/ 57 levels "08/08/2013 02:04:25 AM INFO",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 7 9 10 ...
$ inStock  : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ unitPrice: Factor w/ 1 level "61.12000": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ moq      : Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

                 timestamp       inStock 
1  08/08/2013 02:10:41 AM INFO   100
2  08/09/2013 02:14:17 AM INFO   98
3  08/09/2013 02:27:52 AM INFO   95
4  08/10/2013 02:09:05 AM INFO   90
5  08/10/2013 02:23:21 AM INFO   80
6  08/11/2013 02:40:56 AM INFO   200
7  08/12/2013 01:10:30 AM INFO   195
8  08/12/2013 01:25:35 AM INFO   190
9  08/13/2013 01:14:39 AM INFO   180
10 08/13/2013 01:27:42 AM INFO   178
....
```

(1)The timestamp was created by Python somehow and I don't know how can I easily change this dataframe into a time series type object so I can do some basic time series analysis.

(2)Clearly, you can see there is not only one record for each day. Say for 08/13/2013, there are two records. I want to get the minimum inventory on that day... so group by day and use the minimum as the record. Meanwhile there might also exist some day that doesn't have any data.

So how can I work around that, thanks!

Comment: For converting the timestamp column look at `?strptime`.

Comment: Try... `as.POSIXct( df$timestamp , format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see the second part of your question when I made my comment. `plyr` provides a pretty easy way to do this...

```
#  Make sure you have daily dates and integer for stock
df$timestamp <- as.POSIXct( df$timestamp , format = "%m/%d/%Y" )
df$inStock <- as.integer( df$inStock)

require(plyr)
ddply( df ,  .(timestamp) , summarise , inStock = min(inStock) )
   timestamp inStock
1 2013-08-08     100
2 2013-08-09      95
3 2013-08-10      80
4 2013-08-11     200
5 2013-08-12     190
6 2013-08-13     178
```